# Array of buttons does not work in JavaScript when storing and calling a button

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this problem, the goal of this code is that when I select `5 buttons` from the table ( maximum number of clickable buttons) the `6th` one that I will click, will make the first of five I clicked to be `disabled`, and then let the current one to be clicked. When the body is loaded, a table is created with buttons via `js` Example : I select the numbers : `1-2-3-4-5` and if I click the number 6 number 1 gets disabled or at least does not count between the 5 selected and gets the green class removed. I need to make this thing progressive so I will also need to track what is the "first" button I selected and I thought that the "best" way would be store the first one into an array of buttons.

That seems not to work because I get this error when the 5th button is clicked :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'button')
    at button.onclick
```

And that makes me think that when I access the array it actually can't store the buttons or either does not work. Am I trying to access the array wrongly? `(firstButton = array_btn[previous].button)`  Assuming the input checks already work to verify that no more than 5 buttons are clicked how can I accomplish this goal? Thank you for the help in advance :) I apologize if some part of the code is still in Italian I did my best to set it as understandable as possible.

`HTML :`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Lotto</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stile.css" />
    <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap");
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap");
    </style>
    <script src="lotto.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="createTable()">
    <h1>Benvenuto all'Enalotto !</h1>
    <p class="istruzioni">
      Seleziona dalla tabella sottostante i numeri che vuoi giocare (MASSIMO 5
      !)
    </p>
    <br />
    <table id="tab-punt" class="tabella"></table>
    <br /><br />
    <p id="stampa" class="punt">Stai puntando i seguenti numeri :</p>
    <button onclick="randomArray(); check();" class="bottone" id="btnvinto">
      Scopri se hai vinto !
    </button>
    <p id="vincenti" class="vincenti"></p>
    <p id="vinto" class="perso"></p>
    <br /><br />
  </body>
</html>
```

`JavaScript :`

```
let num = 1;
function createTable() {
  let tabella = document.getElementById("tab-punt");

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let nuovaRiga = tabella.insertRow(-1);

    for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      let nuovaCella = nuovaRiga.insertCell(j);
      nuovaCella.appendChild(createButton(num));
      num += 1;
    }
  }
}

//Creating arrays to store user input
const input = new Array(5);

var click_counter = 0;
var stringa_out = "";
var i = 0;

let lastButton;
let array_btn = [];
let previous;

//Function to create every single button
function createButton(index) {
  let button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  button.classList.add("bot-tab");
  //All buttons will share this class
  button.classList.add("click");
  var text = document.createTextNode(index);
  button.appendChild(text);

  button.onclick = function () {
    let firstButton;
    let currentButton;
    currentButton = this;
    array_btn.push({ currentButton });
    input[i] = index;
    i += 1;
    button.classList.add("verde");
    click_counter += 1;
    if (click_counter === 5) {
      firstButton = array_btn[previous].button;
      firstButton.disabled = true;
      //lastButton = button;
      firstButton.classList.remove("verde");
      click_counter -= 1;
      previous+=1;
    }
  };

  return button;
}
```

Comment: You never initialized `previous`. What is `array_btn[previous]` supposed to be? And then you do `previous += 1`. But if you never assigned anything to it, you can't add 1 to it.

Comment: that block of code is supposed to store the "first" button of 5 into the array, previous is tracking the first button so everytime you store it, it will be the next one. Doesn't `let previous;` make `previous` count as initialized?

Comment: `let previous` declares the variable, but doesn't initialize it. `let previous = 0;` initializes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should fix you issue, if it does not, let me know your end goal, since the way you are going about this is complex, it could be way more simple.

Let me know the goal, I would be able to give you a more simply code to achieve it.

***Notes:***

- Only the code from `'let lastButton;` onwards is included
- See the comment lines starting with `// <-` for explanation

```
let lastButton;
let array_btn = [];
let previous = 0; // <- This should be initialised

//Function to create every single button
function createButton(index) {
  let button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  button.classList.add("bot-tab");
  //All buttons will share this class
  button.classList.add("click");
  var text = document.createTextNode(index);
  button.appendChild(text);

  button.onclick = function () {
    let firstButton;
    let currentButton;
    currentButton = this;
    array_btn.push({ button: currentButton }); // <- you need to assign button property as it is accessed later on
    input[i] = index;
    i += 1;
    button.classList.add("verde");
    click_counter += 1;
    if (click_counter === 5) {
    console.log(array_btn[previous]);
      firstButton = array_btn[previous].button; // <- 'button' property accessed here
      firstButton.disabled = true;
      //lastButton = button;
      firstButton.classList.remove("verde");
      click_counter -= 1;
      previous+=1;
    }
  };

  return button;
}
```

Comment: Yep, it worked perfectly, that was exactly my goal. Thank you so much for the effort you put in the help! :)

Comment: Perfect. I still feel you are complicating the solution but I am not aware of the end goal, so can't say. If you like to simplify the solution just setup a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) and let me know your goal.

Comment: Yes, I think you are completely right, as soon as I have time I will try to set up the project an show it to you. Thanks again

Comment: Sounds good. looking forward to it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any `previous`, `lastButton` etc variables, just a smarter way to add/remove HTMLButtonElements from your array of currently *active* (selected) buttons. Here's a possible solution that uses the simpler CSS Grid instead of a Table:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);


// Enalotto game:

const elGrid = el("#buttons");

// Array to store the active HTMLButtonElements
const playedButtons = [];

const playButton = (elBtn) => {

  const idx = playedButtons.indexOf(elBtn);

  // Remove button if already in array
  if (idx > -1) {
    playedButtons.splice(idx, 1);
    elBtn.classList.remove("is-active");
    return; // Exit function here.
  }

  // Remove first clicked
  if (playedButtons.length === 5) {
    const elBtnFirst = playedButtons.shift();
    elBtnFirst.classList.remove("is-active");
  }

  // Add to array
  playedButtons.push(elBtn);
  elBtn.classList.add("is-active");
};

const newButton = (index) => elNew("button", {
  type: "button",
  textContent: index + 1,
  className: "bot-tab click",
  onclick() {
    playButton(this);
  }
});

const createButtons = () => {
  const buttons = [...Array(90).keys()].map(newButton);
  elGrid.append(...buttons);
};

// Init game:
createButtons();
```

```css
#buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 2rem);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 2rem);
}

.is-active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons"></div>
```

With the above code, when you want to get an array of the values, lotto numbers the user selected all you need is:

```js
const userNumbers = playedButtons.map(elBtn => elBtn.textContent);
// which gives i.e:
// ["12", "45", "2", "5", "86"]
```

Comment: This solution seems to work perfectly too. I'm kind of beginner in html, javascript and css and I am learning this part of developing at school, we haven't seen any javascript library yet but I really apreciate the help that you gave me. I will do some research in order to understand the whole code. Thank you so much for helping and the effort!